# Product details json is not retrieved. Do we get the details only if we have Business and Enterprise plans in scraper api?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-functions

Product details scraping from amazon url(Scraper API).

```
 var request = require('request');
      const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
      var url = req.body.URL;
      console.log("url",url);
      var url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Brand-Spotted-3-Piece-Sweater/dp/B07Q5CDGD7?ref_=Oct_BSellerC_2474958011_0&pf_rd_p=30799821-2ba4-52dc-824a-76c103a34806&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-6&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=2474958011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=GDDXEX526066N6AVQMZJ&pf_rd_r=GDDXEX526066N6AVQMZJ&pf_rd_p=30799821-2ba4-52dc-824a-76c103a34806';

      request(
        {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=API_KEY&url=' + url,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}),
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(body);
        }
      );
      res.status(200).json({ Token: "Success" });
```

The output should be in json format but i was recieving in html format.

Answer (score 0):

The POST request you are doing to the API is `json`. However you can not define the output of the response, as it is set from `scraperapi.com` which comes from `amazon.com`.

From the documentation, `the return value will be stringified, if you want to use it as JSON, you will want to parse it into a JSON object.`

But, first of all, the response has to have `json` format. In this case, the page URL you are accessing is a `html` page.